# How can I create a Kubernetes Secret with Ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm using an Ansible JMeter Operator to do distributed load testing and am having trouble with creating a Kubernetes secret. The operator I'm modifying is [the JMeter one](https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-operator) and the additional YAML I'm adding is as below:

```yaml
- name: InfluxDB Storage Secret
  k8s:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    type: Opaque
    metadata:
      name: azure-storage-account-infxluxdb-secret
      namespace: '{{ meta.namespace }}'
    stringData:
      azurestorageaccountname: 'xxxxxxx'
      azurestorageaccountkey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Is there anything wrong with the YAML definition? I'm modifying the *roles/jmeter/tasks/main.yaml* of the role to add it into my specific namespace.

Comment: Could You provide us output from jmester/tasks/main? What is the error that You encountered?

Comment: Is there a way I can show the output while it's running in a pod in kubernetes? I don't have a dev environment setup for Ansible yet (I keep getting further and further away from what I set out to do!) and might have to shelve my desired changes.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my example, that works for me, hope it help.

```
  - name: CREATE MONGOSECRETS SECRET
    kubernetes.core.k8s:
      state: present
      definition: 
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        type: Opaque             
        metadata:
          name: "{{ secret_name }}"
          namespace: "{{ project_name | lower }}"     
        data:
          config_data.json: "{{ lookup('template', mongo_conn_templates_path + '/config_data.json' ) | tojson | b64encode }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a template lookup to load a file into a secret is the way to go.
The example above is good, but there are 2 things I do differently :

- no need to concatenate the path to the templates. If your template file is in the `templates` directory of the role, you're good.
- no need for the `tojson` filter in your data. Just using plain base64 is enough to load an arbitrary text file as a secret, with the key of your choice (here `config`)

This is a sample from our role configuring Dell CSI drivers for example.

```
- name: Create config secret
  redhat.openshift.k8s:
    state: present
    definition: 
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      type: Opaque             
      metadata:
        name: isilon-creds
        namespace: "{{ dell_namespace }}"     
      data:
        config: "{{ lookup('template', 'config.txt.j2' ) | b64encode }}"
  register: config_secret
```